# Licensing an open source project after reading code of a similar one

Tags: open-source, licensing

I recently contributed some code to an open source library/tool just before I realized that I'd like to re-write this project myself (different programming language and design choices). However, some aspects of the project are just like I would have done them myself or are simply worth "copying". Even if I tried really hard to forget about the original code -- most class names, constants and other stuff just are naturally named the same. The original project's license is AGPL.

- Can I use a different license (e.g. MIT)?  Which ones?
- Will I have to mention the original project somewhere?
- If so, where? And will I ever be allowed to remove the notice (maybe after the two projects have truly diverged after a few years of development)?

Comment: Are you using Github to contribute to this project?

Comment: I did, yes. I plan to release on Github, too.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing / intellectual properties / legal issues, not programming. [[See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846)] for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not a lawyer and this is probably not the correct venue for soliciting legal advice.

However, this is my take, as one FOSS contributor to another.

Generally speaking when you contribute to open source projects, you retain the copyright over the code that you wrote, and you release it under a license that permits everyone to use modify and distribute it.

Thus, you retain the right to relicense code that you so contributed under MIT or another license. That doesn't count as "stealing" the code and erasing the GPL license -- you were the original source and you retain the right to release what was originally yours again under a different license.

In some projects, the leaders may request that people DO transfer copyright, although its pretty rare I think. You should check the licensing statement to be sure. Unless there is something in writing somewhere saying that you explicitly agree to transfer copyright to them, then most likely you retained it.

You do not have the right to relicense other peoples work though. In cases where you modified someone elses code, contributing some changes to their class or something, you probably become joint owners, and at least I would not feel comfortable copying the part that they made and relicensing it without permission.

That's just the text of the code though. If you want to rewrite another program from scratch, using a similar high level plan but different execution, I don't think copyright will encumber you. Intellectual property law can still encumber you if some technique or method in the code is covered by a software patent. But it doesn't sound like that's the case here.

To avoid legal issues, sometimes companies / groups of people will use "clean room design" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_room_design). But iiuc this is just done as a precaution to unambiguously head off any possible lawsuit -- the law does not require that you use such techniques just because you once looked at GPL code, iiuc.

For an example of this playing out, you can look at the history of the MinGW cross compiler project, and the mingw-w64 spin-off of it, which originally began because a private company wanted a version of mingw which supported 64-bit processors and other things, and so used clean room design to reverse engineer the project. The result of this was eventually made fully open source, but was not accepted back into the original mingw project and so there are now two projects. (Hope that this is a fair and impartial summary of the history.)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW#History